# UNIX named PIPE end of file

Tags: python, linux, loops, pipe, eof

I'm trying to use a unix named pipe to output statistics of a running service. I intend to provide a similar interface as `/proc` where one can see live stats by catting a file.

I'm using a code similar to this in my python code:

```
while True:
  f = open('/tmp/readstatshere', 'w')
  f.write('some interesting stats\n')
  f.close()
```

`/tmp/readstatshere` is a named pipe created by `mknod`.

I then cat it to see the stats:

```
$ cat /tmp/readstatshere
some interesting stats
```

It works fine most of the time. However, if I cat the entry several times in quick successions, sometimes I get multiple lines of `some interesting stats` instead of one. Once or twice, it has even gone into an infinite loop printing that line forever until I killed it. The only fix that I've got so far is to put a delay of let's say 500ms after `f.close()` to prevent this issue.

I'd like to know why exactly this happens and if there is a better way of dealing with it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason to use a named pipe vs. a regular file?

Comment: @Mansour Merge complete.

Answer (score 1):

A pipe is simply the wrong solution here. If you want to present a consistent snapshot of the internal state of your process, write that to a *temporary* file and then rename it to the "public" name. This will prevent all issues that can arise from other processes reading the state while you're updating it. Also, do NOT do that in a busy loop, but ideally in a thread that sleeps for at least one second between updates.

Comment: Well, due to some deadlocking issue regarding the linux buffer cache, I can't actually do anything that would cause dirty pages to be created on the cache. That's why I chose a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

What about a UNIX socket instead of a pipe?

In this case, you can react on each connect by providing fresh data just in time.

The only downside is that you cannot `cat` the data; you'll have to create a new socket handle and `connect()` to the socket file.

```
MYSOCKETFILE = '/tmp/mysocket'
import socket
import os
try:
    os.unlink(MYSOCKETFILE)
except OSError: pass
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX)
s.bind(MYSOCKETFILE)
s.listen(10)
while True:
    s2, peeraddr = s.accept()
    s2.send('These are my actual data')
    s2.close()
```

Program querying this socket:

```
MYSOCKETFILE = '/tmp/mysocket'
import socket
import os
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX)
s.connect(MYSOCKETFILE)
while True:
    d = s.recv(100)
    if not d: break
    print d
s.close()
```

Comment: Ye, I considered that first, but I was trying to avoid writing a separate program to talk to a socket (in my case TCP) in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use fuse.
it has python bindings, see http://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuse-python/
this allows you to compose answers to questions formulated as posix filesystem system calls

Comment: This solution seems like an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write to an actual file.  That's not what `/proc` does.  Procfs presents a virtual (non-disk-backed) filesystem which produces the information you want on demand.  You can do the same thing, but it'll be easier if it's not tied to the filesystem.  Instead, just run a web service inside your Python program, and keep your statistics in memory.  When a request comes in for the stats, formulate them into a nice string and return them.  Most of the time you won't need to waste cycles updating a file which may not even be read before the next update.

Comment: Hmm, from my understanding and tests so far, the python code blocks on `open` until another process opens the pipe for reading - with this behaviour, it would _look like_ `/proc`. The problem is, the `open` sometimes doesn't block and that causes the multiple stats being outputted. Creating a normal TCP socket was my first choice but that meant another little program to read the stats. I just wanted to keep things simple and minimal.

Comment: @Mansour isn't writing to an actual file. He's using a named pipe. `write` calls will block until a reader is ready - there won't be any wasting of cycles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `unlink` the pipe after you issue the `close`. I think this is because there is a race condition where the pipe can be opened for reading again before `cat` finishes and it thus sees more data and reads it out, leading to multiples of "some interesting stats."

Basically you want something like:

```
while True:
    os.mkfifo(the_pipe)
    f = open(the_pipe, 'w')
    f.write('some interesting stats')
    f.close()
    os.unlink(the_pipe)
```

*Update 1: call to `mkfifo`*

*Update 2: as noted in the comments, there is a race condition in this code as well with multiple consumers.*

Comment: Wouldn't unlink remove the pipe altogether? Who will re-create it again?

Comment: Woops, good point. Missed a call to `mkfifo` in my example. I'll update it.

Comment: OK, but there will be a race condition between `os.unlink` and `os.mkfifo` if a reader tries to open the pipe.

Comment: You're right. I haven't seen that particular race in practice but I've only tried it out with a single consumer (either `cat` or another Python script).